# Reglas del negocio de una base de datos

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

¿alguien sabe cómo podría implementar las siguientes reglas del negocio para esta pequeña base de datos?  Les agradecería que me pudieran ayudar, muchas gracias.

-Ningún vendedor puede ingresar ventas de clientes que no pertenezcan a su zona.

-Ningún cliente nuevo puede tener asociado un vendedor que no sea de su zona.

-Un cliente puede tener asociado mas de un vendedor por zona.

-Un vendedor no puede pertenecer a mas de una zona de venta.

El script es el siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE juan.zona_venta (

    id_zv INT NOT NULL,
    descripcion VARCHAR(200),

    CONSTRAINT pk_zona_venta PRIMARY KEY (id_zv)
);

CREATE TABLE  juan.vendedor (

    id_v INT NOT NULL,
    id_zv INT NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    apellido VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_vendedor
    PRIMARY KEY (id_v)
);

CREATE TABLE juan.ventas (

    id_v INT NOT NULL,
    id_c INT NOT NULL,
    fecha DATE NOT NULL,
    importe NUMERIC(7,2) NOT NULL,
    iva NUMERIC(7,2) NOT NULL,
    venta_total NUMERIC(7,2) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_ventas
    PRIMARY KEY (id_v, id_c, fecha)
);

CREATE TABLE juan.cliente (

    id_c INT NOT NULL,
    id_v INT NOT NULL,
    id_zv INT NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_cliente
    PRIMARY KEY (id_c, id_v, id_zv)
);

CREATE TABLE juan.comisiones (

    id_v INT NOT NULL,
    mes VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    venta_total NUMERIC(7,2) NOT NULL,
    comision NUMERIC(7,2) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_comisiones
    PRIMARY KEY (id_v, mes)
);


ALTER TABLE juan.vendedor ADD CONSTRAINT fk_zv_vendedor
FOREIGN KEY (id_zv) REFERENCES juan.zona_venta(id_zv)
;

ALTER TABLE juan.cliente ADD CONSTRAINT fk_zv_cliente
FOREIGN KEY (id_zv) REFERENCES juan.zona_venta(id_zv)
;

ALTER TABLE juan.cliente ADD CONSTRAINT fk_cliente_vendedor
FOREIGN KEY (id_v) REFERENCES juan.vendedor(id_v)
;

ALTER TABLE juan.ventas ADD CONSTRAINT fk_vt_vendedor
FOREIGN KEY (id_v) REFERENCES juan.vendedor(id_v)
;

ALTER TABLE juan.ventas ADD CONSTRAINT fk_vt_cliente 
FOREIGN KEY (id_c) REFERENCES juan.cliente(id_c)
;

ALTER TABLE juan.comisiones ADD CONSTRAINT fk_co_vendedor
FOREIGN KEY (id_v) REFERENCES juan.vendedor(id_v)
;
```

¿Creen que se pueda hacer con CONSTRAINTS?

Comment: Los puntos 1 y 2 se pueden hacer con la base datos actual. El punto 3 no se puede porque en la tabla `cliente` el registro se asocia con un vendedor `id_v` no puede asociarse con más de uno. Igual el punto 4, el vendedor se asigna a una zona de ventas `id_zv` no puede asociarse con varias.

Comment: Hola, Lobo
Creo que tal vez eso está mal porque la db yo la estoy haciendo, entonces tal vez en eso está el error, ¿podrías ayudarme a corregir la base para poder tener una buena identidad referencial? Te lo agradecería bastante.

Answer (score 0):

> Ningún vendedor puede ingresar ventas de clientes que no pertenezcan a
> su zona.

> Ningún cliente nuevo puede tener asociado un vendedor que no
> sea de su zona.

Esos dos casos se cubren usando una función que evalúa si el vendedor y el cliente están en la misma zona. Esa función se llama desde un trigger asociado a cada tabla configurado para ejecutarse antes de insertar el registro. Si la zona no es la misma se lanza un error, sino , se inserta el  registro.

> Un cliente puede tener asociado mas de un vendedor por zona

Para esa condición fue necesario agregar una nueva tabla `vendedores_asignados` y remover el campo `id_v` de la tabla `cliente` así se pueden asignar varios vendedores a un solo cliente.

> Un vendedor no puede pertenecer a mas de una zona de venta.

Esa condición ya estaba cubierta ya que en la tabla vendedores se guarda el id de la zona de venta a la que pertenece así que solo puede pertenecer a una.

```
CREATE TABLE zona_venta (
    
        id_zv INT NOT NULL,
        descripcion VARCHAR(200),
    
        CONSTRAINT pk_zona_venta PRIMARY KEY (id_zv)
    );
    
    CREATE TABLE  vendedor (
    
        id_v INT NOT NULL,
        id_zv INT NOT NULL,
        nombre VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
        apellido VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL ,
    
        CONSTRAINT pk_vendedor
        PRIMARY KEY (id_v)
    );
    
    CREATE TABLE ventas (
    
        id_v INT NOT NULL,
        id_c INT NOT NULL,
        fecha DATE NOT NULL,
        importe NUMERIC(7,2) NOT NULL,
        iva NUMERIC(7,2) NOT NULL,
        venta_total NUMERIC(7,2) NOT NULL,
    
        CONSTRAINT pk_ventas
        PRIMARY KEY (id_v, id_c, fecha)
    );
    
    CREATE TABLE cliente (
    
        id_c INT NOT NULL,
        id_zv INT NOT NULL,
        nombre VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    
        CONSTRAINT pk_cliente
        PRIMARY KEY (id_c, id_zv)
    );
    
    
    CREATE TABLE vendedores_asignados(
    
        id INT NOT NULL,
        id_c INT NOT NULL,
        id_v INT NOT NULL,
        
        foreign key (id_c) references cliente (id_c) ,
        foreign key(id_v) references vendedor(id_v)
    
    );
    
    CREATE TABLE comisiones (
    
        id_v INT NOT NULL,
        mes VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        venta_total NUMERIC(7,2) NOT NULL,
        comision NUMERIC(7,2) NOT NULL,
    
        CONSTRAINT pk_comisiones
        PRIMARY KEY (id_v, mes)
    );
    
    
    ALTER TABLE vendedor ADD CONSTRAINT fk_zv_vendedor
    FOREIGN KEY (id_zv) REFERENCES zona_venta(id_zv)
    ;
    
    ALTER TABLE cliente ADD CONSTRAINT fk_zv_cliente
    FOREIGN KEY (id_zv) REFERENCES zona_venta(id_zv)
    ;
    
    
    ALTER TABLE ventas ADD CONSTRAINT fk_vt_vendedor
    FOREIGN KEY (id_v) REFERENCES vendedor(id_v)
    ;
    
    ALTER TABLE ventas ADD CONSTRAINT fk_vt_cliente 
    FOREIGN KEY (id_c) REFERENCES cliente(id_c)
    ;
    
    ALTER TABLE comisiones ADD CONSTRAINT fk_co_vendedor
    FOREIGN KEY (id_v) REFERENCES vendedor(id_v)
    ;
    
    
    insert into zona_venta values(1,'zona 1');
    insert into zona_venta values(2,'zona 2');
    
    insert into vendedor values(1,1,'juan', 'perez');
    insert into vendedor values(2,2,'carlos', 'perez');
    
    insert into cliente values(1,1,'ramon perez');
    
    
    
    -- funcion que evalua si el cliente y el vendedor estan en la misma zona
    DELIMITER //
    
    CREATE FUNCTION evaluar_cliente_vendedor_misma_zona ( id_cliente INT, id_vendedor INT )
    RETURNS INT
    
    BEGIN
    
       DECLARE resultado INT;
    
       SET resultado = 0;
    
       if (select id_zv from cliente where id_c = id_cliente limit 1) <> (select id_zv from vendedor where id_v = id_vendedor)  then
         SET resultado = -1;
      end if;
    
       RETURN resultado;
    
    END; //
    
    DELIMITER ;
    
    
    -- trigger que impide insertar un registro en la tabla si el vendedor y el cliente no están en la misma zona
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER evaluar_misma_zona_tabla_vendedores_asignados 
    BEFORE insert ON vendedores_asignados
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
    
     
     if evaluar_cliente_vendedor_misma_zona(NEW.id_c, NEW.id_v) = -1 then
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'El vendedor no es de la misma zona de venta que el cliente';
     end if;
     
    END$$
    
    DELIMITER ;
    
    
    -- trigger que impide insertar un registro en la tabla si el vendedor y el cliente no están en la misma zona
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER evaluar_misma_zona_tabla_ventas
    BEFORE insert ON ventas
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
    
     
     if evaluar_cliente_vendedor_misma_zona(NEW.id_c, NEW.id_v) = -1 then
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'El vendedor no es de la misma zona de venta que el cliente';
     end if;
     
    END$$
    
    DELIMITER ;
```